# How to Plot x,y coordinates in c3.js chart library?

Tags: javascript, charts, c3.js

How can i pass x,y values to generate a chart where the x values are not automatically sorted? if i use this example the x starts on 2 because its the lowest value.

```
var chart = c3.generate({
data: {
    x: 'x',
    columns: [
        ['x', 50, 80, 2,100, 230, 300],
        ['data1',400, 200, 100, 50, 25, 12]
    ]
}
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to *not* sort the x values, then you need to treat it as a category axis

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1',400, 200, 100, 50, 25, 12]
        ],
        type: "bar",
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'category',
            categories: [50, 80, 2,100, 230, 300],
        }
    }
});
```

See http://c3js.org/samples/categorized.html